# 93 Honda Civic LX - fluctuating revs, poor running

Tags: rough-idle, idle, head-gasket, cylinder-head, water-pump

My Civic has done ~246,000 miles and is now running very poorly.

While driving down Interstate Car bogs down stalls out and there's smoke from front and back.

Spark plugs are fouled out and when they were removed to change them they were wet with gasoline.

3 days before this there was strong smell like gasoline when I started the car and it was not running as strong. While driving it RPMs were fluctuating and it couldn't stay at a constant idle. And appears to run hot while stationary then once moving again it would go back down to normal temperature.

After driving for at least 5-10 minutes it would start to lose power and seem like cylinders were failing.. I would stop take the spark plugs out try to let some of the gasoline inside of the spark plug holes evaporate and try to start it again and it would run okay for a few minutes and then go back to doing the same again.

What's the likely cause(s)?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've edited your question to try and make it a bit more readable - this should hopefully help others understand the situation and get you some useful answers. Hopefully I haven't strayed too far from what you intended but if I have feel free to rollback my edit.

Comment: When did it last have a thorough service/ air fuel oil & filters etc etc

Comment: How many miles did you expect to get on this engine?  My guess is it should last like 200,000 miles or so before things start to wear out. (e.g. valve seals, bearing wear, rear main seal leaking oil, ring/cylinder wear = low compression)  Have you done compression test?  Post results here for each cylinder?